# Canonicalization XML in Java 1.8

Tags: java, xml, apache, canonicalization

I'm trying to do the canonicalization part of XML.
However, I don't know how to connect to Apache.

I have download the package:
http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/santuario/java-library/2_0_8/xmlsec-2.0.8-source-release.zip
But adding it to the project doesn't work. How do I do that?

This is not working:

```
public byte[] canonicalize(byte[] data) throws Exception {
    byte[] result = null;
    try {
        org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();
        Canonicalizer c14n = Canonicalizer.getInstance("http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315");
        result = c14n.canonicalize(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("False");
    }
    return result;
}
```

### My Settings:

[image: my settings]

Comment: Can you explain what 'This is not working' means? Do you get a compile error? A runtime Exception? Please post any messages/stack trace you are receiving.

Comment: Just eclipse doesn't see "org.apache.xml.security.Init.init()" and "Canonicalizer" class.
I don't know where i have to add package apache.

Answer (score 0):

The library is only available as a "source" release, which means you will have to build it yourself.

If you check its contents, you will notice a `pom.xml` file, which means its build process is handled by [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/run.html). Install the tool if you don't already have it, and build the project with the command `mvn install` from inside the library directory.

Once you've done that, you will be able either to use the `.jar` file produced in the process, or reference the library as a maven dependency.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote a bad link. I have library to Java.

Comment: I've never done maven's project. Is it possible to do canonicalization in a different way?

Comment: @Mafika looks like you could use [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/) instead of Apache Santuario. It does have a binary release.

Comment: @Mafika also, I see you're using Eclipse. Using the eclipse-mvn plugin can make the experience of a maven build much less painful (install the plugin, left-clic the source project, maven->mvn install)

Comment: Yes, I used Eclipse, but now I will use IntelliJ.